# wget - save all data (images) from given directory?

Tags: wget

I want wget to scan for sub and sub-subdirectories of:

> domain.com/profile/username/albums/

Then grab every .jpg file from their sources.

Wget should get files like:

> domain.com/profile/username/albums/album1/43434
>
> (...)
>
> domain.com/profile/username/albums/album6/4343

And download every image from their sources (unfortunately these images are on different server).

Is this possible?

I've been playing with -p -A .jpg and -r 1/2/3/4/5 but it grabs everything, like:

> domain.com/profile/anotherusername/albums
>
> domain.com/site/contactus
>
> domain.com/site/anothersite
>
> commercials-for-domain.com/banner/

etc.

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p domain.com/profile/username/albums/album1/43434
```

Works perfectly but with only one page; I'm not sure how to "scan" for different albums and files.

*I need to do this because a friend of mine got her computer stolen and all her pictures are on this page and nowhere else. There are almost 200 of them with div overlays above them so it's hard to save them manually!*

[edit]

The path tree looks exactly like this:

First level:

> domain.com/profile/username/albums/

Second level:

> domain.com/profile/username/albums/1,My Birthday Photos/
>
> domain.com/profile/username/albums/2,Photos_From_2011-09-25/

Third level:

> domain.com/profile/username/albums/1,My Birthday Photos/75893989,
>
> domain.com/profile/username/albums/2,Photos_From_2011-09-25/74893213,

Comment: I think wget needs a file with links. I guess you are not doing wget directly onto her stolen computer and rather to some regular web hosting company that she used. Maybe you can FTP to it? Then maybe there's a chance to do what you want.. i'm not sure how but it might then be a slightly different question, OTOH wget can do FTP I think.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have "directories" per se; the entire structure is fake, even if it does map to an actual filesystem structure.

Comment: I've been digging around and this saves every file I need, but not images linked to it: wget -r --no-parent http://www.domain.com/profile/username/albums - so I guess the "directories" work! :) I have no access to FTP :( Any ideas how to extend this command so it will save images from these files sources? BTW can I got banned for that? Because it grabs the data so fast...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sure you're saying something deep and technically true there(seriously) even though I don't know what you mean.. but one could say that directories since they're logical not physical, are an entirely "fake" structure. What do you mean by "fake", directories are specified in HTTP like GET /LDP/HOWTO/Fundamentals.html HTTP/1.0

Comment: @michail maybe  there's  username/albums/index.html  that links to everything or links to things that link to things.  Try adding -p   see if that gets images

Comment: @michail they could ban you hopefully only temporarily if they did, but you can add -w 1 and it will  pause for 1 second between getting each file

Comment: @barlop: Those are paths, not directories. The difference is subtle but very important.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  well, directories are the elements of a path. I suppose you say not on a web server. So how are you defining the elements of a path on a web server?  btw what is your definition of path and of directory?

Comment: @barlop are you sure -p next to --no-parent will download external .jpg files? I'm still getting all the files I want, just not the images from their sources. Af, we're so close :) But it's still in progress with -w 1 (thanks for that trick, it slows me down a lot, but I hope I won't get banned).

Comment: @barlop: A URL path does not have to map to a filesystem. Certainly if I access `http://example.com/product/54/edit/` in order to edit the properties of product 54, it would make little sense for the path to map to directories and files.

Comment: @michail I think so.. but look at wget domain.com/profile/username/albums  with no switches and look at index.htm or index.html  and you'll see it gets those files linked to. and the -r means it follows from there. It doesn't scan directories for everything.   Maybe they aren't linked to. Who is the actual web host that doesn't offer FTP? they might make an exception or offer an upgrade in the circumstances.  If you knew the names of the images, you could download them with wget.

Comment: wget --no-parent -w 1 -p -r domain.com/profile/username/albums/ gets only .html files like photo4343.html etc., but still none of the contents :( I can download these files manually, there is a huge image on each page... Unfortunately as I said before there is a lot of these images, so it will take a few hours if not days ;)

Comment: @michail  well if you can download them manually then you can download them automatically with wget.  are the numbers sequential? what is the pattern to the filenames?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  ok but HTTP does use GET and  wouldn't that  always refer to directories like the root directory of the web server or some subdirectory from there? and be some mapping to a real directory.

Comment: @barlop: [No.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: @barlop - check out the edit or just the page, here's a link to my friends profile (she has 3 or 4 profiles there): http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy , here's first albums URL: http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/1,Ja/74893332,,1319743984 and second: http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/2,Fotki_z_2011-09-25/75893982,,1319485161 , thanks for your time by the way :) I'm getting all the data as I said, but not the images, I could get all the images and sort them later on my HDD, but I can't get any, at least using -r, because it works ok with singl page.

Comment: @michail  I don't know.. I suppose you could try asking fotka.pl if there's a way to download all images and explain the situation , they're human beings and they have access, so they may offer a way. or there may be some other way though I don't know. your question could be made like a general one for fotka.pl pages.  Regarding wget , this line for this webpage   wget -r -l 1 -nd http://www.scopesux.com/images/girls   works even without -p. But in your example, i'm not sure 'cos wget wasn't really designed for that.

Comment: @michail actually i see a lot of image URLs in the source for that html page

Comment: @barlop, thank you a lot, but I guess it is possible to do what I want and I'll eventually figure it out, there were people mirroring all FB profiles using wget! :) Of course there are URLs in sources :)

Comment: @michail  it may be every image is on that one page.. let's see if we can get every file that ends _p.jpg

Comment: @michail this might be a list of all the jpgs ins the source of that page.. not sure if that's all her ones http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WQ4eVKY9

Comment: @michail just trying wget -i thatfile -w 1   (maybe i should've done a higher -w.. though if i get banned for too heavy use on it it's no big deal) main thing is you don't! maybe -w 3 would've been better but anyway..

Comment: @michail well downloaded those i could zip them and link to them or you could try that line.

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/PE2SFTKx/rr_online.html   or http://www.megaupload.com/?d=T284I4WK    don't know if that's all of them but that is all the pics linked to in the source , all the JPGs .. and is quite a lot.  you could check.

Comment: @michail that was only based on the source code from here view-http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/1,Ja/74892555,    you could find any pages like that, and then save it like http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TxStQ2fk   let's call the file listps.txt  then you can do grep -oE "http.*?jpg" listps.txt   That will give a link to every single jpg. Then you can do wget -i listps.txt -w 3

Comment: @barlop, that's amazing, how did you get all these urls using wget?

Comment: @barlop, unfortunately they are thumbnails mostly, I believe photos end with _500_s.jpg.

Comment: @michail you're right..but the good news is the rest of the filename and URL is the same or similar enough to mechanically change from one to the other.   here is a list where I took the _72 ones and replaced those with their _500_s equivalents, thereby "fixing" them.. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mTUMr8Bm  here are 100 pics. you can do wget -i thatfile -w 3

Comment: @michail  listps2.txt is the list with all the URLs from the source. this picks out all the _72_p ones and adjusts them so they are correct   C:\>type listps2.txt | grep "72_p" | sed "s/_72_p/_500_s/"  | sed "s/amin\.fotka/a.fotka/" >thatfile    Now we have a new list of just the _72_p ones but corrected to _500_s and the correct URL. Each thumbnail that is _72_p has a larger of _500_s with a URL that says a.fotka instead of amin.fotka  So that acommand produces a list of corrected _72_p ones.  then wget -i thatfile -w 3

Comment: @michail  http://www.megaupload.com/?d=30RWXKN9  that's 100 files produced with the method described. not just wget.. Firstly I got the URLs with GREP not wget. wget can grab the URLs from a file of URLs. I also used SED to adjust the URLs.  And if she ever comes to London, then address a msg to me i'll give you my email address and i'll book a hotel with her! i'm in good shape!

Comment: @michail is that all of them do you think? or enough of them? that is all the _72_p ones from that main webpage, adapted to _500_s   That might be everything or pretty much everything.

Comment: If that solution worked for you, and it looks like it would, then can you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. All photos in the 2 albums are retrieved.

As to how, and as can be ascertained from comments I made and with michail's remarks.

There are two albums..
http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/
one has 100 photos, the other 63 photos.

Here the one with 100 of them
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=30RWXKN9
Here's the album with 63 of them
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=CC27NM41

Taking the source code from here, first album
http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/1,Ja/74892555

Extracting the image URLs
All the thumbnails  end in   _72_p.jpg
We don't want them we want the larger versions, they require in the URL that amin.fotka be changed to a.fotka, and _72_p be changed to _500_s

This is the same for the second album.. so for example, for the second album with 63 photos
http://www.fotka.pl/profil/AlekSanDraa2601/albumy/2,Fotki_z_2011-09-25/75893982,,1319485161

here is blist3.txt  A list with all the JPGs listed in _72_p form
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Y2nXfAXT

You can get that with a line like this..

```
C:\>type source.txt | grep -oE "http://.*?\.jpg"  >urls
```

edit the source to remove any miscellaneous parts.. like HTML attributes, obvious things that shouldn't be there.

or use this line which is better and should just get them all without anything miscellaneous to remove.

```
C:\>type source.txt | grep -oE "http://[^ ]*\.jpg"  >urls
```

You have  more URLs  than you want there, for the second album, that command gives 97 and you only want the ones with _72_p in the URL

So | grep -E "72_p"
so you get a list of just the photos you want.

```
C:\>type list.txt | wc -l
```

63
see there are 63 in that file, the right number.

that is all of them in that album. All 63

wget -i list.txt -w 3

http://www.megaupload.com/?d=CC27NM41

So that's all of them, all 163(100+63) of them, from the two albums.

This is the line one would use to take a list of the JPGs
listps2.txt is a file with all JPGs, both relevant ones and irrelevant ones. The relevant ones are in 72_p form, extract the relevant ones with grep. And change them with SED. put them in "thatfile", and you can then do wget -i thatfile -w 3. As I did.

```
C:\>type listps2.txt | grep "72_p" | sed "s/_72_p/_500_s/" | sed "s/amin\.fotka/a.fotka/" >thatfile

C:\>wget -i thatfile
```