# Downloading images from a webpage

Tags: download, webpage, httrack

This beautiful boy periodically updates [his blog](http://ameblo.jp/maofish/) with pics. I want to automate the process of downloading his pics to my computer.

Let's say I want to download the 3 images from [this entry](http://ameblo.jp/maofish/entry-11141191034.html) in his blog.

Instead of right-clicking on each image, I would like to use a more automatic process.

httrack seems like the thing to use. (Let me know if there is anything else.)

It's a little tricky, because the address of the pics I'm trying to get are totally different. For example, the first of the three pics is located at http://stat.ameba.jp/user_images/20120120/20/maofish/3c/99/j/o0480063311745603530.jpg

I tried the following command:

```
httrack http://ameblo.jp/maofish/entry-11141191034.html -* +stat.ameba.jp/* -*.html -*.txt +*.jpg
```

It gets the files I'm looking for, but it also get some other stuff I'm not. The images are hard to find because when they are downloaded they are nested several directories deep.

What are the parameters to give to httrack to just get the images I'm interested in, and save them to the current directory so I don't have to search too hard for them? If there is a better tool to use, what is it?

Comment: I don't know if this will help but it might. The key in this situation was to wget the main html page, then get/filter/grep-command  the image URLs, then amend them to make the actual ones, wget those actual image URLs.   http://superuser.com/questions/351424/wget-save-all-data-images-from-given-directory    That one might've had like 3 "albums" and 3 "main" html pages that had links to all images, then just had to adjust those URLs and download them.

Comment: do you have a few main pages or a main page that links to all of them? I'm not looking at the "beautiful boy" though, sorry!

Comment: I think the main page is the first link in my post. That page will display the newest entry, and from there a person can go back to read previous entries.

Comment: well look man, here's an example with a tree so not as bad as looking at a "beautiful boy".  http://ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/   above those 3 pictures there is a link http://ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/imagelist.html  see if you can then you see you when you click those arrows you get a new html page with a list of images.. you want each of those html page URLs listed in one file, notice each year has a pattern http://ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/imagelist-201012.html <-- 201012 is december 2010.  Then you have all the ones for 2011 that is imagelist-201101.html to imagelist-201112.html then you have 2012..

Comment: so you get a list of all those .html URLs in one file. Then you do for /f %f in (thefile) do type %f >>thefile2   <-- that puts all the HTML from all the files appended into one file called thefile2. Then you filter out the image URLs you want.  Then you just convert something like http://imgstat.ameba.jp/view/d/90/stat001.ameba.jp/user_images/20111230/23/d-out-ko-ki/37/01/j/o0480064011704775550.jpg (which is a thumbnail) into the big version http://stat.ameba.jp/user_images/20111230/23/d-out-ko-ki/37/01/j/o0480064011704775550.jpg

Comment: I did wget http://ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/imagelist.html and it downloaded imagelist.html. But when I tried that for loop, it said syntax error near unexpected token `%f' What is the /f for? Is that syntax correct?

Comment: slight error on my part, this will get you some of the way and i'll add more in the coming days, if you don't see...As an example let's just do it for 20th december 2012(err I mean 2010 december!)  do C:\blah>wget ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/imagelist-201012.html    now once you have that file, do this C:\blah>type imagelist-201012.html | grep -oP "http://.*?view.*?jpg" >alist  That creates a file alist worth looking at.  You will have to download grep to do that, google for gnuwin32 download coreutils and grep and make sure c:\program files\gnuwin32\bin is in the path.  Now look at the file alist

Comment: see that file alist now has a list of URLs of thumbnails. we can then convert them to URLs of the big files but see if you get as far as that with alist.

Comment: download SED as well 'cos we'll be using that to convert the URLS from short to long.  In the meantime, there must be some pattern for converting small URLs to big ones. hopefully it's not too tricky. Go to  http://ameblo.jp/d-out-ko-ki/imagelist-201012.html  and click on a thumbnail and note down the URL. Then click the thumbnail so it's big, and note down that URL. Try to see how with find/replace like find/replace in ms word, you can get from one URL to the other.

Comment: see if you can the take alist(that's a set of URLs to thumbnails from 2010 12) , do a find/replace on it converting it to set of big pics from 2010 12.

Comment: i've got the pattern.. this will convert file alist to file alist2, file alist2 has big thumbnails C:\asdf>type alist | sed "s#http://.*/user_images/#http://stat.ameba.jp/user_ima
ges/#" >alist2    We then want to download those jpgs wget -i afile2 but with a timeout 'cos you don't want them to stop you downloading don't want to overburden their server. not sure off hand how to get that working I tried it but it didn't wait between each so I did ctrl-c.

Comment: c:\blah>wget -w 4 -i alist2    <-- you want -w 4 so it waits some seconds i put 4 seconds there, between downloading each jpg. i'll leave you with that for now, but have you got that far, and are you seeing a method now? one can get it very automated and that's the general thing to do. alist2 is only the jpgs from 2010 12 but it should help you to see a method.

Comment: furthermore, i didn't see your comment earlier 'cos you didn't address it to @barlop.

Comment: I found that if I wget the page and then use sed -n '/<img/s/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' filename.html I can use grep and redirection to put all of the images in a list. How can I automatically download each of these images? I tried piping and redirection to wget, but it doesn't work.

Comment: a list of URLs of images e.g. alist2.lst  ?  wget -w 4 -i alist2.lst   (see 3 comments ago) The -w 4 makes it pause for a bit between each image, you don't want to get banned from accessing their server for example.

Comment: by the way, are you using windows or linux?  what version of sed are you using?

Comment: I'm using linux. sed is version 4.2.1.

Comment: I'm on sed 4.2.1 windows, though on mine it assumes round brackets are literal by default, anyway, the -n and the p are good, and would remove the need for grep, but you also want to make sure the URLs are to big pics not thumbnails, see earlier comments.